# Editing Nested GridView within a GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, nested, edit

I'm kinda new to the asp server controls and I am facing a difficulty on nested GridView.

I have my ParentGV and ChildGV

Opening the Row in the ParentGV is no problem and showing the rows of ChildGV.

What I do here is:

1. postback to ParentGV_RowCommand.
2. get ParentGV from (GridView)sender.
3. get rowIndex e.CommandArgument.
4. find control of "ChildGV" in ParentGV.
5. BindData ParentGV.
6. BindData relevant Child.

data is shown

Even doing Inserts is working fine.
now the **sender** is the ChildGV, right?

What I do For Inserts:

1. postback to ChildGV_RowCommand
2. get ChildGV from (GridView)sender.
3. get the footer data
4. insert data to DB (MySQL)
5. BindData ParentGV.
6. BindData relevant Child.

Insert ok, but ChildGV.Visible is false.

When I click the Edit button on the ChildGV Row it gets all messy.

so what I do on Edit is:

1. postback to ChildGV_RowCommand
2. get ChildGV from (GridView)sender.
3. "climbing" up ChildGV.Parent.Parent for the ParentGVRow.
4. "climbing" up ParentGVRow.Parent.Parent for the ParentGV.
5. make it selected by -> ParentGV.SelectRow(ParentGVRow.RowIndex)
6. define the wanted line to edit in child -> `ChildGV.EditIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)`
7. BindData ParentGV.
8. BindData relevant Child.

I have been looking and reading about it for a while, just doesnt work.

Thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok... found it out.
when the childGV postback on row command I have to save the rowIndex in a global variable and then when I want to bind the ChildGV under the ParentGV I have to use that global variable.

if code is needed please specify.